# Latched comparator output higher than supply

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design, comparator, latch

I am trying to simulate the following latched comparator (the detail analysis of that circuit can be found [here](http://www.slideshare.net/ushaswinichowdary/analysis-and-design-of-a-low-voltage-and-low-power-double-tail-comparator)).

At low clock frequency (200MHz), the circuit works perfectly well . However, when I try to increase clock frequency to 1.25GHz, the comparator doesn't work and the output waveform looks strange.

As you can see, my supply voltage is 1.8V and all signal is less than or equal to 1.8V. But from the waveform Outn, Outp, we can see that these output volatage exceeds supply voltage. 

 Could anyone explain why?

Also why doesn't the circuit work at that clock frequency? How to modify to make it work?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably parasitics; try slowing down the clock edge rate.

Comment: If you read the paper, it shows a modified version of your topology. In fact, the entire point of the paper is to increase the speed of the circuit which you show. The paper suggests that your topology will produce slow results, so why are you surprised? Plus, of course, there is no guarantee that the transistors you are using are fast enough. Why do you think they are? Modify the circuit as the paper shows and try again.

Comment: I want to try that because my friend also use that topology and get it work at 2GHz. However, he used different foundary.

Comment: Down vote for no reason?